# ACF - Using relationship field to select page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently trying to use the ACF relationship field to select which pages I would like a certain piece of code to run on, for example, if I select Page A, Page B and Page C, I would like the work "hello" to be added.

So far, I have the below Relationship field.

```
        <?php
$posts = get_field('which_venue', options);

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
          <?php
          $thisurl = the_permalink(); 
          // echo $thisurl;             

            $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
            if($url == $thisurl) {
    echo "match";
}
?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My idea was to try and matchthe URL with the url selected, meaning if my URL was http://www.example.com/pagea and I had selected Page A, it would display hello, but unfortunately no luck so far.

Does anyone have an idea of another way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest matching against the page ID instead of the URL. You can use `get_the_ID()` inside the loop to get the ID of the page being displayed. Then get the page ID from ACF that your matching against. I don't recall off the top of my head how to do the later part.

Comment: So if you select Page A, B, and D in your relationship field 'which_venue', and the user is on Page A, B, or D, you want special code to run, correct?

Comment: That is correct. I have a solution now. I will post tomorrow for anyone who has a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like this would do the trick:

1. Change your relationship field to save Post IDs instead of Post Object.
2. Once changed, go to your options page, and re-save your field data.
3. Place this code in your page.php file, or wherever you want your code to run:

   ```
   <?php //Check if this page is selected in which_venue

   //Get the selected fields
   $selectedPages = get_field('which_venue', options);

   //Get the current page's ID
   $myID = get_the_ID();

   //Check if the current page's ID exists inside the selected fields array.
   if(in_array($myID, $selectedPages)){
       //Run your code
       echo 'This Page was selected in "which_venue".';
   }else{
       //Run other code
       echo 'This Page was NOT selected in "which_venue".';
   } ?>
   ```